# OutputPanel Not Serializable with DynamicComponent

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I'm having an issue trying to use `dynamicComponent`.  I'm trying to display an outputPanel, but getting a SerializationException. I'm trying to accomplish this with the following code:

In my page I have a button that calls the goPlatform1 method as the action:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Go Platform1" action="{! goPlatform1 }" reRender="mainPanel" 
       disabled="{! isPlatform1Disabled }" />
```

With the idea that it's going to populate a variable called featurePanel:

```
public Component.Apex.OutputPanel goPlatform1() {
    featurePanel = ( (PlatformFeature)t1.newInstance() ).getFeaturePanel();
            return null;
}
```

Used by a `dynamicComponent` tag:

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{! featurePanel }" id="mainPanel" />
```

The `getFeaturePanel()` looks like this:

```
global Component.Apex.OutputPanel getFeaturePanel() {
    Component.Apex.OutputPanel outPanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
    Component.Apex.PageBlock pgBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
    pgBlock.id = 'platform1Block';
    pgBlock.title = 'Platform 1 PageBlock';

    outPanel.childComponents.add(pgBlock);

    return outPanel;
}
```

This produces a `System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: Component.apex.outputpanel` message on the VF page.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there's an issue with your `featurePanel` (which I guess is a public field or property - right?) and View State.

I wasn't able to find direct statement in documentation but in examples Dynamic Visualforce Components were always created and returned in `get` method. So they were not stored as part of view state. Exception that you provided is a clue that something is wrong about it.

So what should help you is adding `transient` keyword to `featurePanel` field/property.

I don't have all the details of your use case but I quickly prepared a simplified example.

VF:

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Go Platform1" action="{!goPlatform1}" reRender="mainPanel"/>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="mainPanel">
            <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{! featurePanel }" id="mainPanel1" />
        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class TestPageController {
    transient Component.Apex.OutputPanel featurePanel;

    public Component.Apex.OutputPanel getFeaturePanel() {
        return featurePanel;
    }

    public void goPlatform1() {
        featurePanel = new Component.Apex.OutputPanel();
        Component.Apex.PageBlock pgBlock = new Component.Apex.PageBlock();
        pgBlock.id = 'platform1Block';
        pgBlock.title = 'Platform 2 PageBlock';

        featurePanel.childComponents.add(pgBlock);
    }
}
```

So the differences are:

1. I skipped the part where you create `FeaturePanel` instance
2. merged those method of `FeaturePanel` with `goPlatform1()` method
3. changed the return type of this method to `void`
4. and I also needed to put `dynamicComponent` under `outputPanel` because otherwise it wasn't refreshed.

And it worked for me... 
Of course in this scenario you'll lose `featurePanel` information when page is refreshed.

Hope my changes weren't too big and this solution still helps you...